How is AC and DC defined?
My professor in my electric machines class defines alternating current as a current whose integral over all time is zero.
However, in all past classes and every article I have found online, AC is any current which changes direction (regardless of period, amplitude, or shift).
Which definition is correct?
Is $$16\cos(t) + 4\, \mathrm { amperes}$$ AC or DC?
Is $$\text{sgn} (\sin(2\pi ft)) + 1/2\, \mathrm { volts}$$ (where \$\text{sgn}()\$ is the sign function) AC or DC?

It is often less about how it is defined and more about what you are interested in your application. For most people a 9V battery is DC but when you AC couple it and amplify by 1e12 it becomes quite the AC.

Did the prof define DC at all? Your question ("AC or DC") implies that anything that isn't AC is then DC, but I didn't see you say that was how they defined it. Some definitions might leave the door wide open for signal shapes that are neither AC nor DC.

I suspect that the professor is defining AC current for the limited purposes of some calculation. Certainly nobody would suggest that an AC power circuit in which the positive or negative excursion is surpressed by a load fed through a half-wave rectifier is somehow not an AC circuit.

In what I think the context of your course is, the DC component of a voltage is important because it results in inductors (including things like motor coils and transformers that are, or will be, important in your curiculum) passing potentially large currents, limited only by the (unwanted) DC resistance. As well as heating, the DC component can cause magnetic materials to saturate or get closer to saturation. The AC component does not have that effect. So your instructor is using a definition that is fit for purpose.
As well, when we say 'DC' we typically mean a voltage or current that is around long enough that AC effects have died down to essentially a steady state. But real voltages and currents begin at some point, so they have some AC component. And your instructor's definition leaves the question of what interval the voltage or current is to be integrated over. Even if the voltage is a perfect sine wave, if we integrate over a non-integral number of cycles, the integral will be non-zero.

Actually intergral of all time, from infinity to infinity, of periodic function is undefined.

@Crowley Integral (not integral over time) of a sine wave is bounded though.

Any integral of sine wave is bounded and defined, except one "touching" infinity, there the value is "somewhere between -1 and 1" and therefore undefined. The correct definition is [true] AC signals have zero intergral over their period.

@Crowley Which only applies to strictly periodic signals. Something like thermal noise would be considered by most to be AC.

When you add AC and DC components together, that's exactly what you get -- a  hybrid signal that has both AC and DC components. The DC component will be important in some forms of analysis, while the AC component will be important in others.
Sometimes you care about the instantaneous behavior of the overall signal, in which case, generic labels like "AC" and "DC" are no longer relevant or useful.

This is what I was going to say. And this should be clearly taught in EE classes.

This definition: -

My professor in my electric machines class defines alternating current
as a current whose integral over all time is zero.

Is problematic given that the positive peak of an otherwise perfect sinusoidal waveform could be 1 nanovolt different to the magnitude of the negative peak of the sinusoidal signal. The integral over a short period of time will appear to be zero but, "over all time" it won't be.
As you get into circuits more you find that the definition of AC and DC are less important.

The professor's definition seems to be comprehensive and correct. Your example doesn't contradict it. The nanovolt of difference makes that current not purely AC. There is a DC component present in it that will have some non zero integral over time. But the actual AC component still has zero integral over long time.

@pakieng: A bigger issue is that the "integral of a signal over all time" isn't a defined quantity.  More accurate would be to say that the DC component of an eternal signal f(t) is the limit as r approaches infinity of the integral with respect to t of f(t)/2r over the range -r to r.  If that limit is non-zero, the signal isn't a pure AC signal.  Note that the latter limit may have an unambiguous defined value even if the infinite integral of f(t)/2r would not have a defined value for any particular r.

If the positive peak is higher than the negative one, then the integral over a full cycle isn't zero, right? (And taking the integral over a partial cycle will not be zero even over a perfect sine wave.)

@ilkkachu are you addressing your comment to me? If so then I agree.

Mathematically, we use terms like "over all time," but practically we mean "over the time frame we're interested in."
There's no mathematically perfect DC voltage, since it would have been there from the Big Bang.  Noise could be considered an AC signal, but not a periodic or predictable one.
In practice, DC holds a known voltage within a certain tolerance for as long as the device is expected to be powered (if not, you have supply issues).  AC has far more options, from pure sinusoids (or, in the complex space, helices) to random noise processes.  Again, though, if you build an oscillator you don't plan for it to operate forever (or in the past), but it should work as long as the oscillator is enabled.
I'd say your examples above would be considered hybrid signals, each with an AC component and a DC component.

Note that the DC component of a signal during a time interval is the integral of the voltage divided by the length of the interval (the average value during that interval, rather than the integral itself), and that the DC component of an eternal signal may be defined even if the infinite integral isn't.

Others have already provided good explanations, but I'll add some examples and additional considerations.
A number of variable signals come with a DC component (sometimes referred to as DC bias or offset).
A number of analogue sensors work this way (microphones, accelerometers, ...). In particular, their signal output is often within their power supply range (e.g. 0-3.3V or 0-5V). This is particularly useful when paired with ADCs that only support positive voltages (also quite common).
As an example, the SparkFun Analog MEMS Microphone Breakout - ICS-40180 has a bias of 1/2 Vcc:

In addition to amplifying the signal, the OpAmp adds a bias voltage of 1/2 VC

Other similar components can also have an output already biased at 1/2 Vcc, or at least have their full dynamic output within their 0-Vcc range.
Some function generators (especially the very cheap ones, or the ones that come in cheaper portable oscilloscopes) will also produce sine waves (or other signals) with a DC component.
The DC component is often present for practical reasons (and may be useful), but it's important to be aware of it when you read or process the signal.
A multimeter in "DC voltage" mode will generally give you that DC component (even if there are AC variations around it).
A multimeter in "AC voltage" mode may have the option to toggle AC Coupling and remove that DC component from the measurement. (Oscilloscopes often have such features too.)
Datasheets of your measurement device can sometimes give you details about high-pass filtering (AC coupling) or frequency ranges (e.g. "True RMS" multimeters).
It can really matter if you make calculations based on those measurements: an RMS calculation will be widely different (and possibly non-sense) if you don't subtract the DC component.
